# Sun Certified Programmer for the Java 2 Platform, Standard Edition 6 question

Tags: java

I am studying for my first Java Cert! Hurah!  Sorry, don't mean to sound so cheezy, but I can't help it :)  Anywho, trying to understand the below question and answer.  I don't get it. . . I don't really use the command line that much (mainly NetBeans and I am getting acquainted with Eclipse).  Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

---

OBJECTIVE: 7.2: Given an example of a class and a command-line, determine the expected runtime behavior.
10)

> Given:

> ```
> 1. class x {
> ```

```
2.   public static void main(String [] args) {
3.     String p = System.getProperty("x");
4.     if(p.equals(args[1]))
5.       System.out.println("found");
6.   }
7. }
```

> Which command-line invocation will produce the output found?

> ```
> a) java -Dx=y x y z
> b) java -Px=y x y z
> c) java -Dx=y x x y z (*)
> d) java -Px=y x x y z
> e) java x x y z -Dx=y
> f) java x x y z -Px=y
> ```

//So the answer is C

REFERENCE:
API for java command
Option C is correct. -D sets a property and args[1] is the second argument (whose value is y)

---

Uhm. . . so how come args[1] is the second argument? i thought "p" would be equal to the String {y x x y z}?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Uhm. . . so how come args[1] is the second argument? i thought "p" would be equal to the String {y x x y z}?

The question is tricky.  In c), we are starting the class `x` with arguments `x y z`.  And the -D option will cause the `x` property to be set to `y`.

So when the class `x` starts:

- `args` will be `String[]{"x", "y", "z"}, and
- `p` will be `"y"`.

We then compare `p` with `args[1]` ... and the two strings are `equal`.

(Of course, in the real world, no person who named their class `x` would survive long enough to receive their first pay check :-) )

Comment: Cool. I get it. Sweeeeeeeeet.  Thanks guys!

Comment: That question is way too tricky.  IF I WERE KING I WOULD CALL THE CLASS "MAIN.JAVA" INSTEAD --- DOESN'T REALLY DETRACT FROM PEDAGOGICAL VALUE.  Cool question, but way too tricky.  (WHEN I AM KING I SPEAK IN CAPS, FYI.)

Comment: @Julius - thanks for demonstrating that monarchy is an outmoded concept :-)

Answer (score 3):

Actually, when you call it as `java -Dx=y x x y z` then `-Dx=y` - setting system property `x` to value `y`, it does not count as an argument, first `x` is the name of the class you call and last "x, y, z" are actual arguments passed to the program.

Additionally, when you set system value using -D commandline argument, it follows common convention that command line arguments are separated with space. That's why value of system property `x` is `y`, not `y x x y z`.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is

```
class x {
```

So that you may almost forget that the first argument after 'java' (except the options) is the class name (which is, 'x' in this case), then the remaining are the input arguments list.

I don't think this is a good question at all. Who will name a class 'x' anyway? 
The person who designed this question should be hanged.